# Kotlin - How to trim all leading spaces from a multiline string?

Tags: string, kotlin, whitespace, trim

`String.trim()` does not work for strings built using `buildString`. For example,

```
val s = buildString {
    append("{")
    append('\n')
    append(" ".repeat(5))
    append("hello")
    append(" ".repeat(7))
    append("world")
    append("}")
}
println(s.trim())
```

This prints

```
{
     hello       world}
```

but I need it to print

```
{
hello
world
}
```

How can I trim indent without writing my own trim method?

Comment: You probably wanted to use `trimIndent()`, not `trim()`.

Comment: `trim()` only removes whitespaces at the start and end of a string. It doesn't remove whitespaces within a string.

Comment: @broot `trimIndent()` doesn't remove all leading white space on a line

Comment: Your example code only includes one newline. Is that correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`trim()` only removes whitespaces from the beginning and end of a whole string, not per-line. You can remove spaces from each line with:

```
s.lineSequence()
    .map { it.trim() }
    .joinToString("\n")
```

Please note that as a side effect, above code converts all line endings to `LF` (`"\n"`). You can replace `"\n"` with `"\r\n"` or `"\r"` to get different results. To preserve line endings exactly as they were in the original string, we would need a more complicated solution.

Comment: We should probably note that this solution doesn't preserve line endings.

Comment: @Joffrey You mean it will convert CR and CRLF to LF, correct? Thanks for noting that.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Thanks for the edit. It should not be a problem most of the time, but we never know the needs of future people who will read this question :)

Answer (score 2):

One liner:

```
s.lines().joinToString(transform = String::trim, separator = "\n")
```

Comment: We should probably note that this solution doesn't preserve line endings.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression to trim leading whitespace:

```
val s = buildString {
    append("{")
    append('\n')
    append(" ".repeat(5))
    append("hello\n")
    append(" ".repeat(7))
    append("world\n")
    append("}")
}
println(s.replace(Regex("""^\s+""", RegexOption.MULTILINE), ""))
```

Output:

```
{
hello
world
}
```